# SELECT with timestamp dynamic returning results from the same table

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, timestamp

I have a table with `id`, `timestamp` and a `code`.

```
ID timestamp code
1  2013-01-01 1
2  2013-01-01 2
3  2013-01-02 1
4  2013-01-02 4
...
11  2013-01-08 1
12  2013-01-08 5
```

I would like to perform a `SELECT` between a period, like a WEEK or a MONTH from this table, and I would like for each day, a `JOIN` from the same table, but a period of a week before.

If I search the day 2013-01-08, I would like for each day, it would be indexed, something like this:

```
ID timestamp code day_before code_before
11  2013-01-08 1 2013-01-01 1
11  2013-01-08 1 2013-01-01 2
11  2013-01-08 1 2013-01-02 1
11  2013-01-08 1 2013-01-02 4
```

For one day, I'm doing this way:

```
SELECT i.id, i.timestamp, i.code, i2.code, i2.timestamp 
FROM 
    table AS i 
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT code, timestamp 
        FROM table 
        WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-01-07'
    ) i2 ON i.id != '0'
WHERE i.timestamp BETWEEN '2013-01-08' AND '2013-01-08';
```

Edited:

When I say one week or another period for the search, it means only that, the period I want to look for. But the search itself will look up each day of this input period and look back the past week. That's why I gave the example of 2013-01-08 and looking back 2013-01-01 and 2013-01-02, the search will go back 7 days. For the input period of one day, I can do, but I pass two or more days, I don't know how to work.

But for two or more days, I have no clue how. Someone can help?

Comment: Your results don't make sense to me.  How are both `2013-01-01` and `2013-01-01` one week before `2013-01-08`?  Can you better explain the logic (by editing the question)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might want something like this:

```
SELECT i.id, i.timestamp, i.code, i2.code, i2.timestamp 
FROM table i LEFT JOIN (
     table i2
     ON i.id != '0' and
         i2.timestamp BETWEEN i1.timestamp - interval '7 days' and i1.timestamp - interval '1 day'
WHERE i.timestamp BETWEEN '2013-01-08' AND '2013-01-08';
```

It compares the time stamps for each row.

Comment: Thanks! With your answer and Darius, I managed to do the search. Now I think I'm getting duplicates rows, but I'm not sure, so I'll investigate more.

Comment: @MarioH.Adaniya . . . I accidentally left in a chunk of your original code.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. You just need to take out the hard-coded dates and replace them by variables. Instead of using a sub-select, you could do the date-based comparison in the Join's "ON" clause.

```
SELECT i1.id, i1.timestamp, i1.code, i2.code, i2.timestamp 
FROM table AS i1 
 LEFT JOIN table As i2
  ON  i2.timestamp BETWEEN (i1.timestamp - 7 DAYS) and (i1.timestamp - 1 DAYS)
WHERE i1.id != '0'
```

Note: The date expression I have used inside "(... ...)" is pseudo code. Replace it with the syntax that works with your DBMS.